# Error wilth building app on android emulator flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I do not know what went wrong but each time i tried to run this code in on the emulator it shows an error in the terminal and  won't run, but once i choose chrome as the testing device it works smoothly , i am trying to use the geolocator package from pub.dev

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void geolocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low,
    );
    print(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            geolocation();
            //Get the current location
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error displayed:

```
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
                                        ^
  symbol:   method isMock()
  location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change compileSDKVersion from 29 to 31

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now